# Could not be loaded image in revolution slider

Tags: wordpress, image, slider, revolution-slider

I have used revolution slider in my site. In that I am facing problem.
The problem is that images in some of the slides not loaded and also it replaces image with dummy.jpg from revolution slider.
Also when I inspected that it shows this error in console.
[image]

So anyone know what is the cause of this issue.
Please help.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is not a code specific issue and and as such should be closed. This question should be put to the support team of the developers who made the plugin.

Comment: Can you please remove "s" from the https and check it again, I hope it would work else It might be causing of SSL issue

Comment: The issue is still same after removing 's' form url'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resized my all slider images and also compressed them. This has solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

You may find that your image slider is loaded but the slides are not showing. Sometimes the images are not properly uploaded or your image slider code files may be causing a code conflict.

If your slider plugin isn’t updated or doesn’t match to your WordPress version, it can also cause a problem with the images. Try simply updating your WordPress and all plugins to the latest versions. It may resolve this issue.

If your images still aren’t appearing, it could be a caching issue. See this guide on [how to clear your cache in WordPress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-clear-your-cache-in-wordpress/) to see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No problem i solved inside plugin, in "alt attribute" of image background select custom and add your text

[image]